# Is it possible to set an external php cookie while processing an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have an api function that is called on an external site which I control. I want to set a cookie for the user in that function on the external site without the user having to actually visit it. Later if the user does visit the site the cookie will be set. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a cookie in an AJAX request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431906/setting-a-cookie-in-an-ajax-request)

Comment: A PHP cookie on an external Server? Please have a look here: [2870371](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie)

Comment: None of these seem to work. Basically what I'm trying to do is run an ajax request on example.com to trigger a script on anothersite.com. On anothersite.com I want to set a cookie to be used on anothersite.com. Everything I have tried to make this happen hasn't worked.